# mysql cyrillic troubleshooting

Tags: php, mysql

**Hi guys!**

So, I have one question: I have some data which is cyrillic. Here is the problem:
    Incorrect string value: `'\xD0\xBD\xD0\xBE\xD0\xB2...'` for column 'title' at row 1.

Here is my code:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
if($link&&isset($_POST['addSticker'])){
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $photo = mysql_real_escape_string(urlencode($_POST['photo']));
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    mysql_select_db('db_name');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (title, description, photo, quantity, price) VALUES ('$title', '$description', '$photo', '$quantity', '$price');";
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8", $link);
    mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and format the code as code by selecting it (with the mouse) and hitting CTRL-K. The way it's currently formatted is very hard to read.

Comment: sorry, I'm totally new to this site..

Comment: No problem. We all were once. Thanks for editing. Btw: there is also Stackoverflow in Russian http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ (just in case you didn't know).

Comment: thx, didn't know it :D

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that your query is vulnarable to SQL injections. It is recommended to [escape your characters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) (MySQLi). This might even solve your problem. The second thing is you're still using mysql API which is deprecated. Instead, you should switch to PDO or mysqli API. In case you have bad collation (escaping input doesn't help), you can also change MySQL collation to one of [these](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-cyrillic-sets.html) so that database can understand these characters.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev Thanks for the edit. Didn't notice.